# boost::dynamic_bitset multi thread issue

Tags: c++, boost

I use boost::dynamic_bitset to keep track of several tcp connections. If it is connected, it is set to 1, otherwise, it is set to 0. And each connection is one thread. Should I need to protect the bit set from multi thread? or It is not necessary since it does not modify the size of bit set after it is created?

Comment: depends on implmentation, but probably yes because hw doesnt store/read single bits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very uncommon that you actually manipulate a single bit when working in a bitset. Usually the following things happen:

1. Load x bytes (x depends on your machine and the actual implementation)
2. Manipulate the specific bit in those bytes
3. Save the x bytes in the bitset's container.

This is not `boost::dynamic_bitset` specific, it also concerns `std::bitset` for example. You should always have a look at the documentation in this case. Since the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/libs/dynamic_bitset/dynamic_bitset.html#set2) doesn't mention explicit thread-safety, you're likely going to have a race condition.

So you should protect your bitset.

Comment: Thanks. Instead of using bitset, is there any better approach without using lock? using atomic integer.

Comment: @MichaelD: That depends on your data structure. If you organize your connections as `class/struct Connection`, you could simply add an atomic bool/flag member `alive` to them. You can also use a collection of atomic variables (e.g `std::vector< std::atomic<bool> >`), however keep in mind that the container itself must not be modified in this case.